# Как в OpenAPI 3.0.0 спецификации (файл формата yaml) указать ограничения на, получаемый с requestBody, формат файла и его объем?

Tags: yaml, openapi

OpenAPI 3.0.0
Конфигурационный файл .yaml

Подскажите пожалуйста какие поля нужно указать, вместо знаков вопроса (пример ниже), чтобы выставить ограничения на получаемые сервером форматы файла и объем этих файлов.

```
post:
  tags:
    - cards
  summary: Add a new card to the store
  operationId: addCard
  requestBody:
    required: true
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: string
                format: uuid
              title:
                type: string
                example: I was hacked
              image:
                type: object
                properties:
                  file:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
                    **???????????????????**
                  id:
                    type: string
                    format: uuid
                  path:
                    type: string
                    example: ./assets/cards/image1.png
                  alt:
                    type: string
                required:
                  - file
                  - path
```